# Anaconda install script fails / VM / Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: bash, virtualbox, installation, anaconda

- Ubuntu hosted on Windows 10 using Oracle's VirtualBox 6.x
- Downloaded latest Anaconda (Anaconda3-2019/10-Linux-x86_64.sh)
- `bash Anaconda3-2019/10-Linux-x86_64.sh` hangs when `Unpacking`

```
Do you accept the license terms? [yes|no]
[no] >>> yes

Anaconda3 will now be installed into this location:
/home/.../anaconda3

  - Press ENTER to confirm the location
  - Press CTRL-C to abort the installation
  - Or specify a different location below

[/home/.../anaconda3] >>> 
PREFIX=/home/.../anaconda3
Unpacking payload ...
  0%|                                                   | 0/291 [00:00<?, ?it/s]^CProcess ForkProcess-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
  File "multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 233, in _process_worker
  File "multiprocessing/queues.py", line 94, in get
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 216, in recv_bytes
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
KeyboardInterrupt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 71, in <module>
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 483, in _chain_from_iterable_of_lists
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
  File "concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 430, in result
  File "threading.py", line 296, in wait
KeyboardInterrupt

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "entry_point.py", line 73, in <module>
  File "site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 960, in __exit__
  File "site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 1147, in close
  File "site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 511, in _decr_instances
  File "site-packages/tqdm/_monitor.py", line 53, in exit
  File "threading.py", line 1044, in join
  File "threading.py", line 1060, in _wait_for_tstate_lock
KeyboardInterrupt
[2755] Failed to execute script entry_point
```

Tried this on both Ubuntu 18.xx and 16.xx VM's.  How do even begin debugging this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, In my case this was related to only having 1 virtual core assigned to the VM.

Try to enable a few more cores and see if that helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works also for me. (VM : centos8 in a Oracle VM VirtualBox, OS : windows 10)